# Factory reset phone with bottom part of touchscreen not working so I can't set it up. ADB functions not working properly

Tags: adb, oneplus-one

The bottom half inch of my phone screen isn't working. Before I factory reset I got around the issue by using the adb command

```
adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,200
```

I have twrp installed but when I try to use that command I get an error

> /sbin/sh: wm: not found

The device does show up in adb devices

Things I did after this:

- try same command with different phone and it worked
- Reflash ROM
- Accidentally delete OS
- Reflash OS
- try again with same error

The device is a OnePlus One

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found there are certain adb commands which do not work in recovery mode. adb shell wm commands are among those.

When I tried this on the other phone it was with it open to the main launcher with adb enabled through the settings.

For anyone else with a similar issue, I believe the only solution is to get a usb to micro usb converter and connect a mouse to your device for the set up, and then enable adb through the settings.